# Navigate to viewcontroller from a subclass function in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, xcode8

I've created a `UINavigationController` with a `UIToolbar`. Inside the `UIToolbar` there are multiple `UIBarButtonItems`. The `UIToolbar` has a subclass which i use to set the toolbar settings and create the `UIBarButtonItems`.

By pressing a `UIBarButtonItem` I want to navigate to another ViewController. As you can see in the code below, I've created a function for `.addTarget`, called "`settingsPressed`".

```
//SetToolbar

class ToolbarClass: UIToolbar {

//Set height of toolbar
override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    size.height = 60
    return size
}

//Toolbar settings
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    //Default
    self.isTranslucent = false
    self.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 48/255, green: 148/255, blue: 172/255, alpha: 1)

    //Buttons

    //Settings
    let settingsBtn = UIButton()
    settingsBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
    settingsBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Settings-Button")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    settingsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.settingsPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    settingsButton.customView = settingsBtn


    self.setItems([settingsButton], animated: false)

}

func settingsPressed() {
   //How to navigate to a viewcontroller?
}

}
```

I've found some swift codes to navigate to another viewcontroller, but these codes don't work in my situation because i'm using a subclass. In this case the ".self.storyboard?" doesn't make sense:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClassesOverviewViewController") as!  ClassesOverviewViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: UIToolbar is a sub-class of UIView class, which does not confirm to the navigation. You have to instantiate the navigation control and push to the viewcontroller from that navigation controller . You can check the  "self.navigationController", it must be returning nil. That is why it would not be working. Check and let me know

Comment: Use delegation (protocols) to achieve ...

Comment: Are you used storyboard ID? There's no any connections as segue ( UIStoryboardSegue )?

Comment: @Mannopson I've tried but it didn't work. I guess because of the answer of Janmenjaya. I'm looking in to it now.

Comment: If you have used storyboard ID in your project? Make sure your storyboard ID is correctly and check " Use storyboard ID " is must be marked as checked. I don't know why, but create a new storyboard constant instead of " self.storyboard? "

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation breaks MVC principles and causes the problems which you shouldn't face at all.
You should not add controller logic (creating new VC and navigating to it) into view (UIToolbar and it's subclass are view elements).

1. First way to fix it: add UIToolbar to storyboard view with added settings bar button item, connect action of bar button item with function from your VC, implement this function to navigate.
2. Second way to fix it: leave subclass of UIToolbar (it is not preferable if you only adding bar button item in subclass), declare public property for settings bar button item, use [target](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617154-target) and [action](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617127-action) to set your VC as target and function from VC as action for settings bar button item, implement this function to navigate.

Comment: The first way is the same as the comment of Janmenjaya if i understand it correctly? I'm trying to fix it this way but can't find out how. I've tried to load the toolbar with all his settings inside the UINavigationController instead of using a subclass. But the UIBarButtonItems don't show up. I'm kind a stuck right now.

Comment: Here is what you need to do in your [storyboard](http://imgur.com/To752xp). On your NC check "Shows Toolbar" on your VC add toolbar with item and connect action with implementation.